# How do I use Route path to go

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to learn react navigation, using route and route path but I seem to be making mistake somewhere, can anyone help me with it?

I tried to keep changing the div and the div that shows the posts but it doesn't show anything now, it was showing the posts and the buttons but couldn't go to

Comment: Your post/question is not very clear. What is the specific issue or problem you face?

Comment: I'm trying to go from App.js to another page which is Profile.js by using the route

Comment: Are you saying you want the app content and the `Profile` component content to be rendered separately on different pages/routes? Routes are not used to "go to pages", they simply render content matched to the current URL path. Use links to navigate.

Comment: yes i want the posts to be in App.js only then when i click the profile button it'll go to Profile.js

Comment: What is the "profile button"? What is `_renderCard`? Can you [edit] to include a more complete and accurate [mcve]? You want this `posts` state to be moved into `Profile` component and rendered there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Component to `element`

```
<Routes>
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile/>} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: `Component` is a valid prop. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#elementcomponent It doesn't work well outside Data routers, but it's still valid.

Comment: thank you, is where im putting the div and routes correct? cause somehow it shows blank page instead

Comment: No it'll work, but you need to simply give a name of the component, not like `element={<Profile/>}`  instead of this you need to give `Component={Profile}`. React will create the element for the Component we gave!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of component you should use element

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile/>} />
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the other existing answer. `Component` is a valid prop. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#elementcomponent It doesn't work well outside Data routers, but it's still valid.